# Custom Error Handler not working in NodeJs Express

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I was studying about error handeling in express and I defined one. It works fine for non async functions. But when it comes to async function the app just breaks.

```
app.get("/products/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const product = await Product.findById(id);
  if (!product) {
    return next(new AppError());
  }
  res.render("products/show", { product });
});
```

I have put the error handler at the bottom of the app like this:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const { status = 500, message = "something went wrong" } = err;
  res.status(status).send(message);
});
```

My custom Error Class:

```
class AppError extends Error {
  constructor(message, status) {
    super();
    this.message = message;
    this.status = status;
  }
}

module.exports = AppError;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your router doesn't know what to do when it the await fails for whatever reason. You can use this catchAsync I made below but you can also do a `try` `catch` statement around your code so it catches the error and goes onto the next task.

The try/catch could look something like this

```js
app.get("/products/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  try{
    const { id } = req.params;
    const product = await Product.findById(id);
    res.render("products/show", { product });
    
  } catch(err) {
    return next(new AppError());
  }
});
```

This is my catch async function that you can use.

```js
module.exports = func => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        func(req, res, next).catch(next);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Your's solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: I didn't have to use catch async. It worked right away.

Comment: Sorry i was learning error handeling and what you mention catchAsync I didn't understand.When i came to the topic I felt stupid. Now it make sense to me. Thank you again.

Comment: Of course! I'm happy it fixed it!